# I want to create a vertically expanding content bar

Tags: cascadingdropdown

Actually, I wanted to create a sidebar with 6 items, which show the content in a dropdown format.

For eg, if you click company, the content about company expands downwards, along with other five menu items. If you click any other item, the above one needs to close and this item  should expand.

I want something like the sidebar in JsFiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

Seems like what you are talking about is similar to jquery Ui's accordion:

Have a look at the link here to get you started: http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Also don't forget to include jquery as well.http://jquery.com